# Insertar relación ManyToMany desde formulario symfony2

Tags: symfony2, formularios, orm

estoy teniendo problemas para insertar/editar una entidad con relaciones MM entre tablas.
Tengo las relacines bidireccionales embarazada-riesgo y embarazada-factor_de_riesgo.
Este es el código del action para mostrar y registrar una embarazada:

```
public function captarAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
            $idEstructura = $request->get('cmfId', 0);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $estructuraOrganizativa = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:EstructuraOrganizativa')->findOneJoinTipoEstructuraOrganizativa($idEstructura);

            if (!is_object($estructuraOrganizativa) || $estructuraOrganizativa->getTipoEstructuraOrganizativa()->getId() !== 6)
            {
                return new Response("Seleccione el CMF al que pertenece la embarazada.", 404);
            }

            $nuevaEmbarazada = new Embarazada();
            $nuevaEmbarazada->setEstructuraOrganizativa($estructuraOrganizativa);

            $form = $this->createForm(EmbarazadaType::class, $nuevaEmbarazada, array(
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('embarazadas_captar', array('cmfId' => $estructuraOrganizativa->getId())),
                'method' => 'POST',
            ));

            if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST')
            {
                $form->handleRequest($request);

                if ($form->isValid())
                {
                    $em->persist($nuevaEmbarazada);
                    $em->flush();

                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('embarazadas_captar', array('cmfId' => $estructuraOrganizativa->getId())));
                } else
                {
                    return new Response($this->renderView('AppBundle:Embarazadas:frmCaptarEmbarazada.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView())), 406);
                }
            }

            return $this->render('AppBundle:Embarazadas:frmCaptarEmbarazada.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'estructura' => $estructuraOrganizativa));
        } else
        {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException("Recurso no encontrado");
        }
    }
```

Exactamente me está sucediendo que el formulario da siempre inválido pero no se muestra ningún error asociado a los campos del mismo, y  en el dev.log no se registra error alguno, solo mensajes de tipo Debug.
Al dar siempre inválido pues no se ejecuta el `$em->persist($nuevaEmbarazada);`

Anh, la entity Embarazada tiene establecido los métodos `remove`, `add` y `get` de las colecciones riesgo y factor_de_riesgo.

Si muestro el formulario listo para editar un registro embarazada, pues se populan correctamente los select (expandidos en forma de checkbox) con los riesgos y factores de riesgos asociados checked, pero al intentar actualizar igualmente la barra de depuración del navegador me retorna un error 406 con el formulario inválido.

Qué pudiera estár enfocando mal a la hora de manejar este tipo de relaciones?

Resulta que revisando la Entity `Embarazada` creo está fallando uno de los metodos setters:

```
public function setFechaUltimaMenstruacion($fechaUltimaMenstruacion)
    {
        if (($fechaUltimaMenstruacion instanceof \DateTime) == false)
        {
            $fum = new \DateTime($fechaUltimaMenstruacion);
            //$fum = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $fechaUltimaMenstruacion);
            $this->fechaUltimaMenstruacion = $fum;
        } else
        {
            $this->fechaUltimaMenstruacion = $fechaUltimaMenstruacion;
        }

        $fecha = clone $this->fechaUltimaMenstruacion;

        $fpp = new \DateTime($fecha->format('Y-m-d'));
        $fpp->modify('+280 days');

        $this->setFpp($fpp);

        return $this;
    }
```

y en el caso de `setFpp($ffp)`:

```
     /**
     * Establece la posible fecha de parto de la embarazada basado en la fecha de ultima menstruacion +280 días.
     */
    public function setFpp($fpp)
        {
            if (($fpp instanceof \DateTime) == false)
            {
                $fecha = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $fpp);

                $this->fpp = $fecha;
            } else
            {
                $this->fpp = $fpp;
            }
            return $this;
        }
```

ahora bien, por qué todo este enredo en estos dos métodos? Resulta que el control del formulario que estable estas fechas es un intput de tipo Text al que le asocio un bootstrap-datepicker, por lo que estos dos campos los introduzco en el formulario dentro de un evento de tipo                 `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` de manera tal que si el formulario es de edición, muestre las fechas correctamente dentro del input.
Y a causa de esto me di cuenta que le está llegando al `setFechaUltminaMenstruacion` un valor de fecha en formato `string` y no `\DateTime`, y es ahí donde el cambio que hice en los metodos set de la entity están fallando.
de todos modos les expongo el código de EmbarazadaType como solicitó en usuario @Muriano

```
    class EmbarazadaType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('nombre', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nombre y Apellidos', 'attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-8'), 'label_attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-4',)))
                //->add('fechaNacimiento', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Fecha de Nacimiento'))
                ->add('numeroIdentidad', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Número de Identidad'))
                ->add('direccionParticular', TextareaType::class, array('label' => 'Dirección Particular'))
                ->add('telefono1', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Teléfono 1'))
                ->add('telefono2', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Teléfono 2'))
                ->add('centroDeTrabajo', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Centro de Trabajo'))
                //->add('fechaUltimaMenstruacion', TextType::class, array('label' => 'F.U.M'))
                ->add('fumConfiable')
                //->add('estructuraOrganizativa', HiddenType::class)
                ->add('factoresDeRiesgos', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:FactorDeRiesgo',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true
                ))
                ->add('riesgos', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Riesgo',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                ))
        ;

        $builder->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event)
        {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if ($data->getId() === null)
            {
                $form->add('fechaNacimiento', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Fecha de Nacimiento'));
                $form->add('fechaUltimaMenstruacion', TextType::class, array('label' => 'F.U.M'));
            } else
            {
                $form->add('fechaNacimiento', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Fecha de Nacimiento',
                    'data' => $data->getFechaNacimiento()->format('d/m/Y')
                ));

                $form->add('fechaUltimaMenstruacion', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'F.U.M',
                    'data' => $data->getFechaUltimaMenstruacion()->format('d/m/Y')
                ));
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Embarazada'
        ));
    }

}
```

De la manera en que me han quedado lo setter de la entity Embarazada, ya se inicia la transacción para el insert pero no llega a ejecutarse la sentencia porque hay un fallo al mappear el tipo de datos Date. Esto es lo que aparece en el dev.log:

```
doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
    request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Error: Call to a member function format() on string" at C:\xampp\htdocs\pami2.local\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType.php line 53 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Error: Call to a member function format() on string at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pami2.local\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Types\\DateType.php:53)"} []
```

**Ampliando la información:**

Resulta que el problema está en la forma en que intento manejar lo campos del formulario referente a fechaUltimaMenstruacion y FechaNacimiento, siendo propiedades de tipo \DateTime

Declaré esos campos como DateTimeType, fuera del evento y dejé los setter del la entity Embarazada normales, es decir una simple asignacion de variables.

en el `captarAction` antes de persistir la nueva entidad calculé la FechaUltimaMenstruacion, y de esa manera funciona perfecto el action.

Ahora bien, de sa manera es poco usable el formulario, y todo parte al inicio, es decir cómo puedo manejar las fechas en el formulario como cadena de carcteres cuando la entidad asociada lo que entiende es \DateTime.
Todo esto para poder emplear un control bootstrap-datepicker.

Comment: Puedes publicar el código de `EmbarazadaType` ??

Comment: @Muriano, he ampliado la duda agregando un posible problema en la entity Embarazada, así como el código de EmbarazadaType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pues al final era muy sencillo, simplemente estaba equivocado en el enfoque que le había dado a la implementación del formulario:
los widgets para captar las fechas los puse de tipo DateType, agregándelo opciones para que se comportaran como un text, y de esa manera asociarle el bootstrap-datepicker correctamente.
y en el action pues simplemente hacer un llamado al `$em->persist($nuevaEmbarazada).`

los setter de la clase Embarazada no debía cambiarlos. Y n hizo falta ningún evento en la clase del formulario, al final e buildForm me quedó así:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('nombre', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nombre y Apellidos', 'attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-8'), 'label_attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-4',)))
                ->add('fechaNacimiento', DateType::class, array(
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'input' => 'datetime',
                    'format' => 'd/M/y',
                    'html5' => false,
                    'label' => "Fecha de Nacimiento",
                    'compound' => false
                ))
                ->add('numeroIdentidad', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Número de Identidad'))
                ->add('direccionParticular', TextareaType::class, array('label' => 'Dirección Particular'))
                ->add('telefono1', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Teléfono 1'))
                ->add('telefono2', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Teléfono 2'))
                ->add('centroDeTrabajo', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Centro de Trabajo'))
                ->add('fechaUltimaMenstruacion', DateType::class, array(
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'input' => 'datetime',
                    'format' => 'd/M/y',
                    'html5' => false,
                    'compound' => false,
                    'label' => 'F.U.M'
                ))
                ->add('fumConfiable')
                ->add('factoresDeRiesgos', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:FactorDeRiesgo',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true
                ))
                ->add('riesgos', EntityType::class, array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Riesgo',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                ))
        ;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que la pregunta quede resuelta?